# how to change segmented button to next on clicked

Tags: sapui5, progress

The segmented button is as follows:

```
<SegmentedButton width="98%">
    <items>
        <SegmentedButtonItem text="INDICATOR1" class="progress" id="before"/>
        <SegmentedButtonItem text="INDICATOR2" class="progress" id="present"/>
        <SegmentedButtonItem text="INDICATOR3" class="progress" id="after"/>
    </items>
</SegmentedButton>
```

and Next button as:

```
<Button text="Next" press="onPressNext" enabled="true"></Button>
```

previous button as:

```
<Button text="Previous" press="onPressPrevious" enabled="true"></Button>
```

[image]

How to write the JS code so that when `Next` is pressed `INDICATOR2` should be active and on second press `INDICATOR3` should be active

And when on `INDICATOR2` if `Previous` is pressed both `INDICATOR2` and `INDICATOR1`(which is current one) should be active

I have no knowledge on JS at least to try , any help so that I would go through it and learn, TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab the list of items from the `SegmentedButton`, get the next or previous item respecitively, and set it as the selected item.

(I added an `id` to the `SegmentedButton` in below example)

```js
sap.ui.define("myController", [
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"
], function(Controller) {
  "use strict";

  return Controller.extend("myController", {
    onPressNext: function() {
      var sb = this.byId("segmentButton1");
      var items = sb.getItems().map(function(itm) { return itm.getId() });
      var idx = items.indexOf(sb.getSelectedItem()) + 1;
      if(idx < items.length) {
        sb.setSelectedItem(items[idx]);
      }
    },
    
    onPressPrevious: function() {
      var sb = this.byId("segmentButton1");
      var items = sb.getItems().map(function(itm) { return itm.getId() });
      var idx = items.indexOf(sb.getSelectedItem()) - 1;
      if(idx > -1) {
        sb.setSelectedItem(items[idx]);
      }
    }
  });
});

sap.ui.require(["sap/ui/core/mvc/XMLView"], function(XMLView) {
  XMLView.create({
    definition: $('#myView').html()
  }).then(function(oView) {
    oView.placeAt('content');
  });
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script id='sap-ui-bootstrap' src='https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js' data-sap-ui-theme='sap_fiori_3' data-sap-ui-libs='sap.m'></script>
  <script id="myView" type="sapui5/xmlview">
    <mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" controllerName="myController">

      <SegmentedButton width="98%" id="segmentButton1">
        <items>
          <SegmentedButtonItem text="INDICATOR1" class="progress" id="before" />
          <SegmentedButtonItem text="INDICATOR2" class="progress" id="present" />
          <SegmentedButtonItem text="INDICATOR3" class="progress" id="after" />
        </items>
      </SegmentedButton>

      <Button text="Previous" press="onPressPrevious" enabled="true" />

      <Button text="Next" press="onPressNext" enabled="true" />

    </mvc:View>
  </script>
</head>

<body class='sapUiBody'>
  <div id='content'></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, but when I am on Indicator2 and press `previous`both indicator2 and indicator1 must be active and one more is when on indicator1 disable `previous`

Comment: @Codenewbie I don't know if that is possible with a `SegmentedButton`. The cardinality of `selectedItem` is 0..1 (see [docu](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.SegmentedButton/associations)), so I believe only one button can be active at once.

Comment: oops, any alternative to achieve the same , instead using a segmented button here?

Comment: Yeah I have read it, would be great if the same can be achieved the other way

Comment: I guess you could place some [`ToggleButton`s](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.ToggleButton/sample/sap.m.sample.ToggleButton) next to eachother and have them act as one `SegmentedButton`. It would be a bit of work to get them to work like the SegmentedButton though (it would be a separate question altogether).

Comment: I knew this only after you have mentioned it, should I now edit whole thing?

Comment: I believe it might be better to ask a new question and leave this one here for other people who may be able to use the SegmentedButton in their code. Then in the new question you can be more specific about using ToggleButtons as a SegmentedButton (+ your next/previous requirement)

Comment: hey mate, I have asked a new question here could you please look in to it...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58516055/how-to-achieve-same-like-segemented-button-with-toggle-buttonsugg-change-to-n

Answer (score 0):

I think you create event like `onclick` and change OR add style class for example `active` attribute

```
<items>
        <SegmentedButtonItem text="INDICATOR1" class="progress active" id="before"/>
        <SegmentedButtonItem text="INDICATOR2" class="progress" id="present"/>
        <SegmentedButtonItem text="INDICATOR3" class="progress" id="after"/>
</items>
```

and when you click next then you have to remove active class from `INDICATOR1` and then append `active` class to next indicator

```
<items>
        <SegmentedButtonItem text="INDICATOR1" class="progress" id="before"/>
        <SegmentedButtonItem text="INDICATOR2" class="progress active" id="present"/>
        <SegmentedButtonItem text="INDICATOR3" class="progress" id="after"/>
</items>
```

Comment: Try to Read Xml Dom [w3 intro to Xml Dom](https://www.w3schools.com/XML/dom_intro.asp)

Answer (score -1):

Please write an onclick function for the next button something like below

```
function onNextClick(){
//Make the css of INDICATOR1 normal and INDICATOR2 || INDICATOR3 active
}
```