# How to achieve same like Segemented button with toggle button(sugg) ,change to next onclicked

Tags: button, sapui5

As learnt from previous question of mine([how to change segmented button to next on clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58503375/how-to-change-segmented-button-to-next-on-clicked)) , I used a Segmented button to do so as:

[image]

My expected results were:

1. when Next is pressed `INDICATOR2` should be active and on second press `INDICATOR3` should be active.
2. when on `INDICATOR2` if Previous is pressed both `INDICATOR2` and `INDICATOR1`(which is current one) should be active.

As I am using segmented button here, the 2) can't be achieved ,and also was suggested using a toggle button would do instead a segmented button.

so I tried as,

```
<HBox id="toggleButton1">
    <ToggleButton text="BUTTON1" enabled="true" pressed="true" press="onPress">
    </ToggleButton>
    <ToggleButton text="BUTTON2" enabled="true" pressed="false" press="onPress">
    </ToggleButton>
    <ToggleButton text="BUTTON3" enabled="true" pressed="false" press="onPress">
    </ToggleButton>
</HBox>    
<Button text="Previous" press="onPressPrevious" enabled="true"> </Button>
<Button text="Next" press="onPressNext" enabled="true"> </Button>
```

[image]

For this ,

**How can I write JS code such that :**

1. when Next is pressed `BUTTON2` should be active and on second press `BUTTON3` should be active.
2. when on `BUTTON2` if Previous is pressed both `BUTTON2` and `BUTTON1`(which is current one) should be active.
3. How can I set these Toggle Buttons width set to whole page(tried my luck `display: block; width=100%` in CSS but couldn't work)

I have no knowledge on JS at least to give a try , any help so that I would go through it and learn so, TIA

Comment: Some questions: 1) Do you want to keep the functionality of the segmentedButton (aka if you press one it deactivates the others)? 2) What happens if you press previous when button3 is selected? Does it select button2 and 3? Or all three? Or nothing?

Comment: 1) yes it should deactivate others 2) sorry , forgot to mention, all three should be active/selected

Comment: One more question: If multiple buttons are enabled and I click one, will it still deactivate the others? Or just the one you clicked? (note that this would leave no active buttons at all)

Comment: It should not be disabled either, once it is enabled it should be enabled only, also when on button3 and pressed `previous` all are active (now on button2) and then again I press `previous` even now all must be active. am I clear?, its like link, 3 buttons have 3 links and say redirecting to 3 pages, now when multiple are enabled and I click on one it should just go to that page no effect on other buttons here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample of using the three `ToggleButton`s as one `SegmentedButton`. I am caching the list of buttons in a local variable, since there is only one group of buttons. You could adapt it to support multiple such groups if needed, by either adding more local variables, or by getting the relevant list of buttons each time.

If <kbd>next</kbd> is pressed, it jumps to the next button. If <kbd>previous</kbd> is pressed, it enables *all* previous buttons. If a toggle button is pressed, it disables all others, much like a `SegmentedButton`.

As for the size, you need to set a few flexbox related properties. `fitContainer` on the `HBox` so it stretches 100% and `growFactor=1` on the toggle buttons so they actually use all that space. Even then, it seems the buttons themselves don't like stretching much, so I set an additional CSS style to force them.

```js
sap.ui.define("myController", [
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"
], function(Controller) {
  "use strict";

  var toggleButtons1;

  return Controller.extend("myController", {
    onInit: function() {
      toggleButtons1 = this.byId("toggleButtons1").getItems();
    },

    onPressNext: function(e) {
      for (var i = 0; i < toggleButtons1.length - 1; ++i) {
        if (toggleButtons1[i].getPressed()) {
          toggleButtons1[i].setPressed(false);
          toggleButtons1[i + 1].setPressed(true);
          break;
        }
      }
    },

    onPressPrevious: function() {
      for (var i = toggleButtons1.length - 1; i > 0; --i) {
        if (toggleButtons1[i].getPressed()) {
          toggleButtons1[i - 1].setPressed(true);
        }
      }
    },

    onPress: function(e) {
      var btn = e.getSource();
      if(!btn.getPressed()) {
        btn.setPressed(true);
        return;
      }
      for (var i = 0; i < toggleButtons1.length; ++i) {
        if (toggleButtons1[i] != btn) {
          toggleButtons1[i].setPressed(false);
        }
      }
    },
    
    onPress1: function(e) {
       this.onPress(e);
       alert("Do something here!");
    }
  });
});

sap.ui.require(["sap/ui/core/mvc/XMLView"], function(XMLView) {
  XMLView.create({
    definition: $('#myView').html()
  }).then(function(oView) {
    oView.placeAt('content');
  });
});
```

```css
.fullWidthButtons button {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script id='sap-ui-bootstrap' src='https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js' data-sap-ui-theme='sap_fiori_3' data-sap-ui-libs='sap.m'></script>
  <script id="myView" type="sapui5/xmlview">
    <mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" controllerName="myController">

      <HBox id="toggleButtons1" fitContainer="true" class="fullWidthButtons">
        <ToggleButton text="BUTTON1" enabled="true" pressed="true" press=".onPress1">
          <layoutData>
            <FlexItemData growFactor="1" />
          </layoutData>
        </ToggleButton>
        <ToggleButton text="BUTTON2" enabled="true" pressed="false" press=".onPress">
          <layoutData>
            <FlexItemData growFactor="1" />
          </layoutData>
        </ToggleButton>
        <ToggleButton text="BUTTON3" enabled="true" pressed="false" press=".onPress">
          <layoutData>
            <FlexItemData growFactor="1" />
          </layoutData>
        </ToggleButton>
      </HBox>

      <Button text="Previous" press="onPressPrevious" enabled="true" />
      <Button text="Next" press="onPressNext" enabled="true" />

    </mvc:View>
  </script>
</head>

<body class='sapUiBody'>
  <div id='content'></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I believe this matches you requirements, but if not, feel free to comment.

Comment: My goodness, this is perfect,thanks a ton sir....last thing, how about adding a link to each button and when clicked display a text/simple form(In space between toggle buttons and Next and Previous) ,so that my previous comment need would satisfy !

Comment: Do you mean you want each button to do something different? You can just use three separate press functions then. I've changed my example to make button1 show an alert for example; while still keeping the other functionality.

Comment: exactly...that's far a good idea to just show an alert!! thanks, similarly can we do it for other two buttons as well?

Comment: Here I am unable to see the Next and Previous buttons , May I know why... https://www.codepile.net/pile/QJdkRDG7       Is this due to growFactor="1"?

Comment: I figured it out mate, it's due to fitContainer="true" and if set to "false" then we can see those buttons down? but may I know the reason why it is set to "true"?

Comment: @Codenewbie: It was set to true to make it stretch the whole width as you asked. But it seems it works the same without it so I guess you can leave it on false.

Comment: If "Button1" is active can we disable clicking button2 and button3 similarly with other buttons?, still looking for this mate